# Let $\Sigma$ be a positive definite with some negative entries. What is $\frac{\partial}{\partial \Sigma}( \sum_{j = 1}^D \log \Sigma_{jj})$?

Tags: matrices, statistics

And if computing this is not straightforward, what are some additional assumptions we can use? When $\Sigma$ has all positive entries, this is straightforward with Jacobi's formula.

Comment: So, how is your function defined, if e. g. $\Sigma=0$? Also note: For positive **definite** matrices, all diagonal entries are strictly positive.

Comment: Good point. I mean positive definite matrices.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \Sigma}\left( \sum_{j = 1}^D \log \Sigma_{jj}\right) = \text{Diag}\left(\frac1{\Sigma_{1,1}},\ldots,\frac1{\Sigma_{D,D}}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Take any analytic function and its derivative
$\big\{f(z),f'(z)\big\},\:$ evaluate it using
a square matrix argument $\{A\},\,$
then calculate its trace:
$$\eqalign{
\def\BR#1{\Big(#1\Big)}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\phi &= \trace{f(A)} \\
}$$
The gradient of $\phi$ with respect to $A$ can be found on $\sf Page\:12$ of the
[Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi//matrixcookbook.pdf)
$$\eqalign{
\grad{\phi}{A} &= f'\!\LR{A^T} \\
}$$
In the current problem
$$\eqalign{
f(z) = \log(z), \qquad f'(z) = z^{-1},\qquad A=\Sigma=\Sigma^T \\\\
}$$
Thus the answer to the question posed in the title is
$\,\large\Sigma^{-1}$